# How to connect a ENC28J60 or ENC424J600 to a KSZ8091 PHY and from PHY to an unmanged strapped configuration to a KSZ8863 or other switch

Tags: switches, design, ethernet, phy, reference

How would one go about connecting MAC chip to a PHY and then to a switch for dual ports for daisy chaining? Rather be a strapped configuration for use in unmanaged mode so no need for MCU software changes and extra SPI and chip select lines on PCB for layout. Currently using a PIC24EP running microchips MLA TCP/IP stack using an ENC28J60 to a MagJack. Just looking for a simple solution and or reference design. Microchip has so many different chips and options makes it look to complex. Just want a dumb switch so can have dual ethernet ports instead of just one for daisy chaining devices together. Thanks in advance. Just want to keep the KISS principle.

Comment: the ENC28J60 and ENC424J600 have their own PHY

Comment: maybe the use of ethernet breaks the KISS principle   ... have you seen this?  https://www.pjon.org/SoftwareBitBang.php

Comment: Jstola, so I could just connect them to say a KSZ8863 switch chip and have dual ports ?